# AMD r9 280x Drivers for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, fglrx, amd-graphics

I can't install AMD driver on *Ubuntu 16.04*.

I took a look at [Install-amd-drivers-r9-280](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663579/install-amd-drivers-r9-280) 
and [AMD-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux](http://www2.ati.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf) but I don't seem to understand how to install.

Answer (score 1):

`fglrx` is no longer supported on 16.04. AMD discontinued support for its Linux driver, and it isn't compatible (you will break your installation if you attempt to install `fglrx` on 16.04).

For now, you have to stick with the open source drivers. AMD may be releasing a proprietary driver for Linux that works with 16.04, but it probably won't support very many cards.

Here's a comparison of how the default drivers on 16.04 compare to `fglrx` on 14.04, if you want to take a look:

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu-1604-amd&num=1

Comment: The open source drivers meaning the one that I don't install? Because it doesn't seem to detect my gpu as being a 280x. I just need to detect and understand what card it is. Is the only solution to change it to a 14.04?

Comment: The open source driver is the generic one that comes pre-installed on Ubuntu. It's used automatically. If Ubuntu doesn't detect the card type and that's something you need, you'll have to go back to an older version for now.